# Calculating distance between coordinates in different dataframes

Tags: r, coordinates, distance

Suppose I have the following two dataframes

```
dfA <- data.frame(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
dfB <- data.frame(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
dfAB <- map2_df(dfA, dfB, str_c, sep=",") %>%
  rename_all(~ str_c('C', seq_along(.)))

dfC <- data.frame(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
dfD <- data.frame(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
dfCD <- map2_df(dfC, dfD, str_c, sep=",") %>%
  rename_all(~ str_c('C', seq_along(.)))
```

What I looking for is to find the distance between coordinates in the first dataframe and the second, so I get a third dataframe with the distance between the first cell of dfAB and the first cell of dfCD, and the distance between the 2nd cell of dfAB and the 2nd cell of dfCD and so on; i.e. call columns C and rows R, I would like the distance between

```
dfAB        and     dfCD
C1 C2 C...          C1 C2 C...  
R1 R1               R1 R1   
R2 R2               R2 R2
... ...             ... ...
etc
```

What I am looking for is the distance between dfABC1R1 and dfCDC1R1, dfABC1R2 and dfCDC1R2, dfABC2R1 and dfCDC2R1, etc.

When I try using

```
dist(dfAB,dfCD)
```

I get the error: Error in dist(dfAB,dfCD) : invalid distance method

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Note about the error message

- Your `dist(dfAB, dfCD)` troughs error, because second argument of `dist()` is character string describing the method for distance calculation (e.g. "euclidean");
- Coordinate tuples in your `dfAB` and `dfCD` data frames are character strings. So even if `dist()` allowed you to calculate distance between each element of two data frames, it would through error.

My approach isn't much elegant, but probably it is the point you can start to think of how to approach your data.

#### Data

```
set.seed(60007561)

dat <- split(rpois(60, 2), paste0('df_', rep(letters[1:4], each = 15)))

for(i in names(dat)) {
  assign(
    i, 
    data.frame(split(dat[[i]], rep(letters[1:5], each = 3)))
    )
}

# inspect the data

head(
  do.call(
    cbind,
    lapply(
      list(df_a, df_b, df_c, df_d), 
      cbind, 
      data.frame(' ' = rep(' ', 3), check.names = F)
      )
  )
)

#   a b c d e   a b c d e   a b c d e   a b c d e  
# 1 1 2 1 2 3   0 2 1 2 1   5 0 2 2 0   2 5 2 3 3  
# 2 5 0 2 0 3   2 5 1 2 3   0 0 4 2 2   3 1 1 1 2  
# 3 3 2 1 3 0   4 2 0 2 2   0 3 1 2 0   2 2 5 1 4
```

#### Sulution

Make two tibbles with columns `a...e` where each column contains data frames with columns `x, y` corresponding to the data from data frames `df_a`, `df_b`; and `df_c`, `df_d` respectively. First resulting tible corresponds to *from points*, and second tibble corresponds to *to points*:

```
df_ab <- as_tibble(lapply(map2(df_a, df_b, ~ list(x = .x, y = .y)), as.data.frame))
df_cd <- as_tibble(lapply(map2(df_c, df_d, ~ list(x = .x, y = .y)), as.data.frame))
#df_ab
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#     a$x    $y   b$x    $y   c$x    $y   d$x    $y   e$x    $y
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     0     2     2     1     1     2     2     3     1
# 2     5     2     0     5     2     1     0     2     3     3
# 3     3     4     2     2     1     0     3     2     0     2
#
#df_cd
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#     a$x    $y   b$x    $y   c$x    $y   d$x    $y   e$x    $y
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     5     2     0     5     2     2     2     3     0     3
# 2     0     3     0     1     4     1     2     1     2     2
# 3     0     2     3     2     1     5     2     1     0     4
```

Calculate euclidean distance between from *from data* to *to data*:

```
distances <- map2_df(
  df_ab,
  df_cd,
  ~ sqrt((.x$x - .y$x)^2 + (.x$y - .y$y)^2)
)

#distances
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#       a     b     c     d     e
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  4.47  3.61  1.41  1     3.61
# 2  5.10  4     2     2.24  1.41
# 3  3.61  1     5     1.41  2
```

*Note that table above represent distances from each points for columns a...e, from first table, to corresponding points in second table*

Plot distances for column `a` (to verify the approach, or just for fun):

```
sgms <- data.frame(
  x    = df_a$a,
  y    = df_b$a,
  xend = df_c$a,
  yend = df_d$a,
  l    = round(distances$a, 1)
  ) %>%
  mutate(lx = (x + xend) / 2, ly = (y + yend) / 2)

ggplot(data = sgms, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_segment(lty = 3, arrow = arrow(10, ,'closed', ends = 'last')) +
  geom_label(aes(x = lx, y = ly, label = l)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), pch = 21, size = 3.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = sprintf('(%d, %d)', x, y)), vjust = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = xend, y = yend), pch = 22, size = 3.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = xend, y = yend, label = sprintf('[%d, %d]', xend, yend)), vjust = -2) +
  expand_limits(y = c(-.5, 5.5), x = c(-.5, 5.5)) +
  ggtitle('Distances btw df_ab, df_cd; col. a') +
  ggthemes::theme_tufte()
```

[image: dist]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Do you also have a suggestion if my initial dataframes have uneven rows and I want to apply the value from the cell C1R1 of df 1 to every R of C1 in df 2?

I.e: 

df_c <- c(1:5)
df_d <- c(11:15)
df_cd <- as_tibble(lapply(map2(df_c, df_d, ~ list(x = .x, y = .y)), as.data.frame))

But now the distance between every row of C1 in tibble 1 with r1 of  C1 in tibble 2 (only 1 row in tibble2).
I think I need for(i in seq_along(df_cd):

Dist2 <- map2_df(
df_ab,
df_cd,
for(i in seq_along(df_cd){
dist3[,i] <- dist3[,i] ~ sqrt((.x$x - .y$x)^2 + (.x$y - .y$y)^2)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @utubun, the use of `dist` is a problem in your example.

`dist` is helpful to calculate distance between elements in a matrix. For example:

```
R> m1 <- matrix(1:8, nrow=4)
R> m1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    7
[4,]    4    8

R> dist(m1)
         1        2        3
2 1.414214                  
3 2.828427 1.414214         
4 4.242641 2.828427 1.414214
```

Note that the euclidean distance between row [1,] and row [2,] is 1.4, which is similar to the distance between coordinates of (1,5) and (2,6) or `sqrt(2)`.

In your case, you don't need a matrix comparisons between all of your points - you sound most interested in distances between pairs of coordinates in two matrices.

As mentioned by @utubun, you need to have numeric values for your coordinates. For example, you could do:

```
mat1 <- matrix(apply(dfAB, 1:2, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ',')))), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
mat2 <- matrix(apply(dfCD, 1:2, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ',')))), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
```

And that would give you two numeric matrices with 2 columns each, which could be considered as your coordinates:

```
R> mat1[1:5,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    3    2
[3,]    4    4
[4,]    1    5
[5,]    0    4

R> mat2[1:5,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    2
[2,]    3    2
[3,]    2    3
[4,]    4    0
[5,]    3    2
```

To get your distances, you could create a simple function to calculate euclidean distance:

```
euclidean_distance <- function(p, q){
  sqrt(sum((p - q)^2))
}
```

And then call the function row-wise through your two matrices of pairs of coordinates:

```
matrix(sapply(1:nrow(mat1), function(x) euclidean_distance(mat1[x,], mat2[x,])), ncol = 5, byrow = FALSE)
```

Which will give you your final matrix of distances:

```
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
 [1,] 3.162278 1.000000 4.472136 1.414214 1.414214
 [2,] 0.000000 0.000000 2.236068 1.000000 2.000000
 [3,] 2.236068 4.472136 5.385165 1.000000 1.000000
 [4,] 5.830952 2.236068 4.242641 3.605551 3.605551
 [5,] 3.605551 3.162278 1.000000 1.414214 2.000000
 [6,] 2.828427 2.000000 2.000000 2.000000 2.236068
 [7,] 1.414214 2.236068 2.236068 2.828427 1.414214
 [8,] 1.000000 4.000000 2.828427 2.000000 2.000000
 [9,] 3.000000 1.000000 1.000000 2.000000 1.000000
[10,] 2.236068 2.828427 4.123106 1.414214 1.000000
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(5)

dfA <- data.frame(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
dfB <- data.frame(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
dfAB <- map2_df(dfA, dfB, str_c, sep=",") %>%
  rename_all(~ str_c('C', seq_along(.)))

dfC <- data.frame(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
dfD <- data.frame(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
dfCD <- map2_df(dfC, dfD, str_c, sep=",") %>%
  rename_all(~ str_c('C', seq_along(.)))
```